# Type "{children: Element;}" is missing the following properties from type "Props": processes, setProcesses, updating, setUpdating, getProcesses

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-typescript

i'm learning React Context and typescript at the same time and i'm using a project that i've build as a test.

After i created my context i'm trying to use it on a component where the following error is showing: Type "{children: Element}" is missing the following properties from type "Props": processes, setProcesses, updating, setUpdating, getProcesses in App.tsx at .

The thing here is that children props will be the components in the app level that will be nested inside the context and i wont pass props from anywhere else.

I've researched anywhere but i could not understand what it means.

Thanks in advance!

interface.tsx

```
 export default interface Props {
  children?: any;
}

export default interface Process {
  processes: Array<string>;
  setProcesses: (active: any) => void;
  updating: boolean;
  setUpdating: (active: boolean) => void;
  getProcesses: () => void;
}
```

App.tsx

```
import React, { FC, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import Menu from "./Components/Menu";
import "./App.css";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import CreateProcess from "./Components/CreateProcess";
import DataTable from "./Components/DataTable";
import CourseTable from "./Components/CourseTable";
import { ProcessProvider } from "./context/ProcessContext";

const App = () => {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <ProcessProvider>
        <Router>
          <Menu />
          <Switch>
            <Route path="/novoprocesso" render={(props) => <CreateProcess />} />
            <Route
              path="/processosconcluidos"
              render={(props) => <DataTable />}
            />
            <Route path="/" render={(props) => <CourseTable />} />
          </Switch>
        </Router>
      </ProcessProvider>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

ProcessContext.tsx

```
import { createContext, FC, useState } from "react";
import { collection, getDocs } from "firebase/firestore";
import { db } from "../firebase";
import Props from "../Interface/Api";
import Process from "../Interface/Api";

const ProcessContext = createContext<Process>({
  processes: [],
  setProcesses: (active: any) => null,
  updating: false,
  setUpdating: (active: boolean) => null,
  getProcesses: () => null,
});

export const ProcessProvider: FC<Props> = ({ children }) => {
  const [processes, setProcesses] = useState<Array<any>>([]);
  const [updating, setUpdating] = useState<boolean>(false);

  const getProcesses = async () => {
    const processCollectionRef = collection(db, "processes");
    const data = await getDocs(processCollectionRef);
    setProcesses(data.docs.map((doc) => ({ ...doc.data(), id: doc.id })));
  };

  return (
    <ProcessContext.Provider
      value={{ processes, setProcesses, updating, setUpdating, getProcesses }}
    >
      {children}
    </ProcessContext.Provider>
  );
};

export default ProcessContext;
```